# Excel VBA Finding a string and inserting a column on loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that has headers that can go from P1 to P# (whatever that number is).

I want to build a macro that starts out by finding P2 and inserts a column and will continue doing this for all the P's(until it hits P#). It will then take those created columns and make the cells width: 6. I  reused a formula to find the cell, but I don't know where to go from there.

'Find P1 in sheet 1

```
SearchString = "P2"
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
            ' loop through all sheets
            For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook
                    'Find first instance on sheet
                    Set cl = sh.Cells.Find(What:=SearchString, _
                    After:=sh.Cells(1, 1), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False)
                If Not cl Is Nothing Then
                    selectcell
                    ' if found, remember location
                  With ActiveCell.insertcolumn
                End If
            Next
```

How do I make this formula select and insert a column, then do it on repeat for all Ps?

Comment: Do you want to insert a column or a row? You start by saying you want to insert a column, then you end by saying you want to insert a row.

Comment: Whoops sorry, column

Comment: Do you want the new column to be to the left or right of the existing one?

Comment: I wasn't aware one could insert a column to the right, but If that's the case (and if it would make it easier) the inserted column needs to go to the right, but should start at P1 not P2 then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes your first sheet has the headers you are looking to use as a baseline in the first row. This will insert new columns to the right of the existing column and resize it.

```
Public Sub addColumns()
    Dim intHeaderRow as Integer
    intHeaderRow = 1
    For i = sheets(1).usedrange.columns.count to 1 step -1
        addColumn(sheets(1).cells(intHeaderRow, i))
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub addColumn(byval SearchString as string)
    Dim intColumnFound as integer

    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    ' loop through all sheets
    For Each sh In Worksheets
        'Find first instance on sheet
        Set cl = sh.Cells.Find(What:=SearchString, _
        After:=sh.Cells(1, 1), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not cl Is Nothing Then
            intColumnFound = cl.Column
            sh.Columns(intColumnFound + 1).Insert
            ' if found, remember location
            sh.Columns(intColumnFound + 1).ColumnWidth = 6
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You had a comment to "remember location" when the value was found. I'm not sure if you needed that, so I stored it in intColumnFound, but it will be overwritten on the next sheet and not used in this code.